# Error in the application of the spread to the lakers data set of the lubricated package

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, spread

I am trying to analyze how many points each Lakers player scored between 2008 and 2009, presenting the result per year, based on the dataset lakers of the lubridate package.

I'm trying the following code:

```
date <- lubridate :: lakers

date <- date %>%
  mutate (Year = str_sub (date, 1, 4))%>%
  filter (points> 0 & team == 'LAL')%>%
  select (Year, player, points)%>%
  group_by (Year, player)%>%
  summarise (Total_points = sum (points))%>%
  ungroup ()%>%
  spread (player, points)
```

But it fails in the spread and presents the following error:

```
Erro: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `var` has the wrong type `function`.
ℹ It must be numeric or character.
```

I would like to know what the problem is. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem is that you forgot that when you summarised `points` you gave the name of `Total_points` to it. You are calling `points` in the last line. This error says that your varible was not found. Just correct the name of the variable in the last line:

```
date <- lubridate :: lakers

date <- date %>%
  mutate(Year = (str_sub(date, 1, 4))) %>%
  filter(points> 0 & team == 'LAL')%>%
  select(Year, player, points)%>%
  group_by(Year, player) %>%
  summarise(Total_points = sum(points))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  spread(player, Total_points)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @LuizZ, I had not attempted this...

Comment: @VeltonSousa - you're welcome. Please accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: I tried to accept, but I still don't have the minimum reputation to accept.

Comment: Hi @VeltonSousa, there is no reputation requirements to accept answers. Please see how to accept here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . You just need to click the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thank you @LuizZ, I'm a beginner here in the environment. I appreciate the support.